# Forward IP address to localhost ssh tunnel

Tags: iptables

I've setup an ssh tunnel so that I can access HTML devices on a server's private sub-net.  For example:

```
$ ssh jamie@10.10.10.10 -L 48884:192.168.100.14:80
```

allows me to put `http://localhost:48884` in my local browser and connect to the sub-netted devices web page.

Now, I have an application that is using the `192.168.100.14` address on my local machine and I'd like to setup an IPTables entry so that it will forward requests to `192.168.100.14:80` to `localhost:48884`.

Would this be close to what I want?

```
# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 192.168.100.14 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:48884
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Any Traffic destined to TCP 80 on eth0 must be forwarded to TCP 48884 on loopback interface 
 sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:48884
# Then allow forwarding from standard NIC to loopback (assuming eth0 is the standard NIC)
 sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```